# Using lib in dll for c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, static-libraries

I have some problems with `dll`. When I make `dll` without using of `lib` files (which I need), everything is fine. But when I'm trying to use some functions in `dll` that uses functions in `lib` then some exception appears:

```
System.DllNotFoundException, cant load a dll module (exception from HRESULT:0x8007007E).
```

`dll` file is in correct place. 
P.S. using Visual Studio 2010.

What could be wrong?

Comment: So you mean you're trying to use some method in lib file which doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

if you are making a new class you should reference the default dlls.
in example when you make a new class library and want to use a messagebox in your code , 
you should first reference that required dll in your program(i dont mean your dll,i mean dot net default dll like system.windows.forms) and then add using something; in the top of your class.

example : we want use messagebox in a class library then :
1. first from solution explorer right click the project > add reference ,now reference manager opens now from left tabs click assemblies then framework and then find and select system.windows.forms
2. now its time to use it in our program first add this line in very top of your class file

```
using System.Windows.Forms; //add this line in top of your class
```

after that we can use messagebox without any compiler errors.

keep in mind any other dll files should be referenced this way but in windows form applications default lib files are referenced by default

Answer (score 0):

More detail in the question will get you better answers. But with current information, the most likely cause is that the lib file you are referencing or one of its dependencies is unavailable. This could be because it is not in your GAC or your runtime location, a file format conflict, or a number of other things.

I'm assuming that everything compiles without errors, of course. Again, please add detail if this is not what you need.